# Trying to create DataGridView from key-value pairs in C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, linq-to-xml

In a Windows Form application, I'm trying to create a DataGridView with two columns: one for the key given by an XML element and one for the value of said XML element. This is my code so far:

```
        this.myData = new DataGridView();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(myData)).BeginInit();

        myData.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 42);
        myData.Name = "myData";
        myData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1060, 585);
        myData.TabIndex = 32;

        foreach (XElement xElem in xInfoItems)
        {
            numItems++;
        }

        myData.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        myData.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        myData.Columns[0].Name = "Key";
        myData.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "key";
        myData.Columns[1].Name = "Value";
        myData.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "value";

        List<myRow> data = new List<myRow>();


        foreach (XElement xElem in xInfoItems)
        {
            data.Add(new myRow(xElem.Attribute("key").Value, xElem.Value));
        }

        myData.DataSource = data;

        myData.Refresh();

        this.PerformLayout();
```

I have confirmed that all of the information in `data` is being loaded via foreach, so that part is working. My problem is that the grid displays, but nothing shows up on the grid. What am I doing wrong? I'm not very good with this data type so I apologize if it's something obvious.

## UPDATE

I figured out that I hadn't set myData up properly in the Design view. After adding the myRow class, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may lie in your myRow class. When I was trying to reproduce your code, I first defined "key" and "value" as public fields of the myRow class as so:

```
public class myRow {
  public string key;
  public string value;

  public myRow( string Key, string Value )
  {
     key = Key;
     value = Value;
  }

}
```

This caused the bound rows to show up but the text was not in the cells. When I changed both of them to properties, the binding worked much better:

```
public class myRow{
  private string _key;
  public string key
  {
     get
     {
        return _key;
     }
  }

  private string _value;
  public string value
  {
     get
     {
        return _value;
     }
  }

  public myRow( string Key, string Value )
  {
     _key = Key;
     _value = Value;
  }
```

}

Comment: This didn't fix it, but what interested me is that you said that you saw something display with your old method - all I see is a blank grid.

Comment: Did you do anything special when setting up the DataGridView? I just created it in the visual designer

Comment: Is your code running exactly as you've posted it? If so, you might be missing a call to EndInit() on DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the modifications I made on your code can help. (I just have focused on the part where you create the columns and add the rows, using a DataTable).

```
this.myData = new DataGridView();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(myData)).BeginInit();

myData.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 42);
myData.Name = "myData";
myData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1060, 585);
myData.TabIndex = 32;

foreach (XElement xElem in xInfoItems)
{
    numItems++;
}


// Here we create a DataTable with two columns.
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

foreach (XElement xElem in xInfoItems)
{
     //Here we add rows to table
     table.Rows.Add(xElem.Attribute("key").Value, xElem.Value);
}

myData.DataSource = table;

myData.Refresh();

this.PerformLayout();
```